# Contact form 7 post to .asp

Tags: php, post, asp-classic, wordpress

Is it possible to post the form contents of Contact Form 7 form fields to an awaiting .asp page? My form has four input fields and one hidden field. Name, Telephone, Email, HowFoundUs, Refer. I want to post those input values to the following .asp page:

clientsite.com/default.asp?name=xxxxxx&telephone=xxxxxxxx&howfoundus=xxxxxx&email=xxxxx&refer=xxxxxxx

I have been searching through the plugin files and have yet to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to change the "action" attribute in the form using this [Filter Hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hook_in_your_Filter)
**wpcf7_form_action_url**. You could add the hook into your theme's **functions.php** and then just process the form data in your ASP page. 
Another option is to use Javascript to change the **action** attribute of the form.

I hope it helps.

Comment: If you use this filter, you will lose features like validation. Moreover, for this filter to work, you must disable the JS from CF7

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @agarassino for the answer, for anyone who finds this here is the solution.

Add the following to your functions.php and change the URL as necessary:

```
apply_filters( 'wpcf7_form_action_url', 'clientsite.com/default.asp?name=xxxxxx&telephone=xxxxxxxx&howfoundus=xxxxxx&email=xxxxx&refer=xxxxxxx');
```