# Change action in Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form-7

Would modify the action of Contact Form 7 once sent the mail.

I follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177844/how-to-change-form-action-url-for-contact-form-7) and woks fine. But my fom is in a Bootstrap Modal, and I wish they would keep open on submit.

My code is. 
In function PHP

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url'); function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url() {  return 'http://saviacomunicacion.com.ar/test2014#sala-de-prensa'; }
```

And in the Aditional Settings field

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');
```

This redirect the URL, but it´s not sending the mail.
I wish i could send the mail and keep the modal open to show the response: Your mail was send correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc](http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/) there is another way to accomplish the redirect. Just add some piece of code to the plugin dashboard.
Or you can do custom js function

in the plugin options

```
on_sent_ok: "customFunction();"
```

and somewhere in the code

```
<script>
    function customFunction() {
        // show your modal here
        $('#myModal').modal();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not working, the page still reload, i want to send mail and keep modal show, but without reloading the page. I tried with this `j(document).on('mailsent.wpcf7', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  j('#urlModal').modal();
 });` But not working

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution with this code. When form submit, the Modal closes after 1 second. 
Instead of keeping Modal open, i wait 1 second after close, to show the response of the sending.

```
j(".form-horizontal").live("submit", function(){
        j.post(this.action, j(this).serialize(), function(){
            //this callback is executed upon success full form submission close modal here

        }, "script");
     //this is to wait 1 second until close
        setTimeout(function() {j('.modal').modal('hide');}, 1000);          
        return false;
    });
```