# Captcha in WordPress custom form

Tags: php, html, wordpress, captcha

I have custom form in WordPress site. Tracking ip address, checking referer page, validating email address.
Still receiving spam subscriptions.
Tried Bestwebsoft CAPTCHA, really simple CAPTCHA but not able to prevent spamming.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried following for my purpose - https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/add-google-recaptcha-wordpress/

This is perfect example for how to add Google captcha in custom `wordpress/PHP/HTML` forms.

Answer (score 1):

Using Contact Form 7 - Plugin will help to create Google Captcha, using api key.

This might help you.

Comment: Does this plugin allow to add CAPTCHA in custom form?

Comment: @Developer Yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks for your hint.Found required answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177844/how-to-change-form-action-url-for-contact-form-7

Comment: @Developer if found it helpful, please upvote the answer and check it with correct