# How to submit Wordpress form from Contact form 7 (specific ID) to another URL

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm a novice in wordpress trying to work with Contact Form 7 plugin. I'd like a specific cf7 form to be submitted to external URL. I searched and found these references and utilized them.

https://babelscribe.nz/wordpress-3/contact-form-7-change-action-url/
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290373/contact-form-7-custom-post-action
[how to change form action url for contact form 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177844/how-to-change-form-action-url-for-contact-form-7)

I had put this in my wp-config.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Then, I put this in my functions.php

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');
function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url() {
    return 'https://myurl.com/index.php';
}
```

With this, I was able to submit *all* of contact form 7 to myurl.

However, now I wanted to change this and submit forms to URL depending on form ID. So, I used this to submite a contact form with ID=78 to myurl.com

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');
function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url(){
    global $wpcf7_contact_form;
    if ($wpcf7_contact_form->id === 78){
        return 'http://myurl.com/index.php';
    }  
}
```

But, this did not work. I'm not able to understand why this is happening when I'm following the exact solutions reported by above referred references.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Change global **$wpcf7_contact_form;** to **global $wpcf7;** and use **$wpcf7->id()** to get form ID

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177844/how-to-change-form-action-url-for-contact-form-7 may also be helpful if you're interested in changing the form action by the id of the page it's located on.

Comment: Thanks @КириллМеркушев, I have tried it already. It didn't help.

Comment: Thanks @JustinR.  I have to use only contact form ID